# How do I get the first Image off of [insertblog].tumblr.com/random?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm trying to grab the first image from a tumblr post that is selected by using [blog].tumblr.com/random which redirects to a random post.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var link = "http://simplyfoodgifs.tumblr.com/random";

   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: link,
    dataType: "json"
    }).done(function() {
       $(this).find("img").first().find("src")({
           $('body').append("<img src='" + this + "'/>");
       });
    });
</script>
```

I haven't got it working yet, any help?  Should I be using the API?  I don't see how to make use of /random with the API.

Comment: This won't work as javascript has a same origin policy, and you can't get the HTML from another page with ajax, it either has to be JSONP or you have to use your server to get the content.

Comment: So is it possible to do it with JSONP?

Comment: Yes, if you're accessing a service that supports JSONP. You can't get the HTML from a regular page with JSONP, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: When I do change the datatype to jsonp, it is able to find a random post, but I get this error in the console

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://simplyfoodgifs.tumblr.com/post/42957677972#_=_".

So is it accessing the redirected url?